# getting data from my localhost and flashing it on the screen?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to take data that I put in a MySQL table on my localhost (xampp) and display it on the screen followed by the next image. It looks like I am getting a blank space for an image but when I try to post the image to the screen nothing happens. right now I have 3 images in my database. my database is spacedream my table is dream and my columns are id which auto increments and image which takes image URLs from another page. Here is the faulty code:

```
<?php

 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1900"); 
 if (!$db) {
 die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }

 $db_select = mysql_select_db("spacedream",$db);
 if (!$db_select) {
 die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }

?>

<html>
<head>

<title>flash</title>


<head>

<body>

 <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dream", $db);
 if (!$result) {
 die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
 }

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<img src = \"\" id = \" " . $row["id"] . " \" width = \"500\" height = \"500\"  style = \"position: fixed; bottom: 50; right: 200;\"/>";
 }
?>




<script>
<?php


 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "var img" . $row["id"] . " = \"" . $row["image"] . "\"";
 }
?>


setTimeout(function imgOne(){document.getElementById("1").src = img1; document.getElementById("1").width = "600"},200);
setTimeout(function imgTwo(){document.getElementById("2").src = img2; document.getElementById("2").width = "600"},300);
setTimeout(function imgthree(){document.getElementById("3").src = img3; document.getElementById("3").width = "600"},400);
</script>


</body>

</html>




<?php
 mysql_close($db);
?>
```

if anyone has any idea what is bad with this code your response will be a big help! thank you very much.

Comment: id's can not start with a number, so, your id's are wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but it might help. If you only have three images in the db at present, how do you intend to deal with the various javascript functions? I don't think the method you are using is the way forward as you'll need to generate a new function for each image - which seems totally unneccessary.

```
<?php
 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1900") or die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 $db_select = mysql_select_db("spacedream",$db)or die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>flash</title>
    <head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $vars = array();
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dream", $db) or die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
            /* 
               Loop through the recordset just once - 
               otherwise you need to rewind the recordset
            */
            echo "<img src='' id='img".$row["id"]."' width=500 height=500  style='position:fixed; bottom:50px; right:200px;' />";/* style position requires a unit - px, %, pt etc */
            $vars[]="var img" . $row["id"] . " = \"" . $row["image"] . "\";";/* The variable declaration eeds a trailing semi-colon to terminate it */
        }
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
        <?php
            echo implode( PHP_EOL, $vars );
        ?>
        /**/
        function imgOne(){document.getElementById("img1").src = img1; document.getElementById("img1").width = 600 }
        function imgTwo(){document.getElementById("img2").src = img2; document.getElementById("img2").width = 600 }
        function imgthree(){document.getElementById("img3").src = img3; document.getElementById("img3").width = 600 }

        setTimeout( imgOne,200);
        setTimeout( imgTwo,300);
        setTimeout( imgthree,400);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    mysql_close($db);
?>
```